# different vc-git-grep-template for different directory (project)

Tags: vc-git-grep

I'm trying to use `vc-git-grep` and it uses `vc-git-grep-template`

It asks

1. query
2. file extension
3. directory to search for

It is nice,but 2,3 are rather repetitive for a project.
Is there a convenient way to set file extension/directory to search for, based on current directory a buffer is at?

If I'm on python project, I'd like 2=*.py 3=root of project directory (where `.git` is located)

Comment: [Per directory-local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) are probably what you need (or, at least, one way to do what you want).

Comment: As NickD wrote. One more way: since `vc-git-grep` runs "git grep searching for REGEXP in FILES in directory DIR", `project-find-regexp` (bound to `C-x p g` by default) might work for you. It finds "all matches for REGEXP in the current project’s roots. With C-u prefix, you can specify the directory
to search in"